# Find duplicate values and move to different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, excel-2007

I have two columns as below:

```
4   10
20  5
20  20
70  20
60  50
80  70
5   90
20  60
100
```

I need a macro to find the duplicate pairs and move them to a separate sheet so the current sheet looks so:

```
4   10
20  50
80  90
100
```

and sheet 2 looks like this:

```
20  20
20  20
70  70
5   5
60  60
```

[image: SO14278314 example]

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to my problem. All the codes and formulae I've tried so far either move all the `20`'s instead of just two pairs of them (as there are only two pairs in both columns) or leave them as is.

I have about 300 entries per day to sort through and it changes completely on a daily basis. Any help or guidance on my problem will be highly appreciated.

How can I achieve the result indicated?

Comment: I dont understand what do you need in sheet 1 and 2, because you need to delete duplicate by columns? or by rows? or bothS? can U be more clear please.

Comment: ... I cannot understand how you get the values which go into Sheets 1 & 2... I don't see how those values are the duplicates / Uniques - For example, why is 20 in Sheet 1??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Here is one example.

Try this. I have commented the code so you will not have a problem understanding it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim lRowColA As Long, lRowColB As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim aCell As Range, ColARng As Range, ColBRng As Range

    '~~> Set input Sheet and output sheet
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Start Row in output sheet
    j = 1

    With wsMain
        '~~> Get last row in Col A & B
        lRowColA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lRowColB = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your actual data range in Col A and B
        Set ColARng = .Range("A1:A" & lRowColA)
        Set ColBRng = .Range("B1:B" & lRowColB)

        '~~> Loop through Col A
        For i = 1 To lRowColA
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                '~~> Check if there are duplicates of Col A value in Col B
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ColBRng, _
                .Range("A" & i).Value) > 0 Then
                    '~~> If found write to output sheet
                    wsOutput.Cells(j, 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                    wsOutput.Cells(j, 2).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value

                    '~~> Find the duplicate value in Col B
                    Set aCell = ColBRng.Find(What:=.Range("A" & i).Value, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    '~~> Clear the duplicate value in Col B
                    aCell.ClearContents
                    '~~> Clear the duplicate value in Col A
                    .Range("A" & i).ClearContents

                    '~~> Set i = 1 to restart loop and increment
                    '~~> the next row for output sheet
                    i = 1: j = j + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        '~~> Sort data in Col A to remove the blank spaces
        ColARng.Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

        '~~> Sort data in Col B to remove the blank spaces
        ColBRng.Sort Key1:=.Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: hi,  sorry for the late response,  was not at work,  code worked perfectly.  i honestly would not have been able to figure it out.  thank you for the code and for the comments - helps me learn more about vba.  thanks to everybody for the quick responses.

Comment: @Siddharth, sorry to bother again, have tested the code before and it worked, now that i have brought actual totals in, the code returns incorrect results. i have played with it untill i could understand it and will try and explain. if i put the following totals into sheet one 5.05 5 0.55 5.19 5.5 19.55 1.9 0.19 19 5.05 19.55 0.55 5 5.5 the return results in sheet1 gives me a 5 and on sheet2 it gives me a 5 on both sides. it should not show the 5 on sheet1 as it has been matched with another one in column A already. i think the amounts are too close to each other. thanks for the help.

Comment: can you upload a workbook with your sample values in wikisend.com and share the link here? Lemme have a look at your data

Comment: will do, give me a few minutes to figure out how.

Comment: cant access any file hosting sites from the work pc.  will upload when i get home this afternoon. thank you

Comment: @Siddharth, figured it out, i recorded a makro where i used "find" and changed the options to search for the entire cell and not just part and compared it to your code.  just had to change "LookAt:=xlPart" to "LookAt:=xlWhole".  now it realy is perfect.  thank you for everything.

Comment: @SiddharthRout `+1` I had another solution, but I saw yours accepted ;)